Application of Ramsey theory/pigeonhole principle or graph theory
Context: there are a lot of questions I've seen in textbooks similar to this, and I want to figure out how I should go about trying to prove this:
If you have some set of $n$ binary states that are either on or off across some time period, and you're given two conditions like 1) there is a subset of size $k$ where all of the states are on at some point in time and 2) all subsets of size $k$ have less than some number $p$ states on at once across all snapshots in time,
It asks how to prove if both cases are sufficient to cover all possible on/off distributions across a time period for some $n,k,p$ and genuinely I'm lost. I know theres something with pigeonhole principle where you can be like minimizing the number of states that are on at any given time but I don't know what to do please help!

I believe your two conditions are mutually exclusive for $p\leq k$.
